# Removing duplicates and filtering based on a boolean property from array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two array of objects with these properties:

```
const a = [{name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: false},
  {name: 'Kelly',email: 'kelly@mac.com',flag: true}];
const b = [{name: 'Rana',email: 'rana@mac.com',flag: true},
  {name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: true},
  {name: 'Hank',email: 'Hank@mac.com',flag: false}];
```

I want to remove all the duplicates containing the flag of false value but both duplicates have flag of false then I just want to keep one of them. But if any object doesn't have any duplicates then I want to keep it regardless of it's flag property. I tried this to remove duplicates but couldn't filter by the flag property.

```
let cs = a.concat(b);
   cs = cs.filter((c, index, self) => 
index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.email === c.email  
))
```

Expected output would be like this:

```
[{"name":"Anna","email":"anna@mac.com","flag":true},
{"name":"Kelly","email":"kelly@mac.com","flag":true}, 
{"name":"Rana","email":"rana@mac.com","flag":true},
{"name":"Hank","email":"Hank@mac.com","flag":false}]
```

Comment: Can you show us what is your expected output?

Comment: the question is not clear. You want to remove duplicate from the `b`?

Comment: Your question confusing because, you have mentioned `keep those only containing the flag of true value` but in expected output you have added 1 record with false flag `{"name":"Hank","email":"Hank@mac.com","flag":false}` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you already know that `a` doesn't contain duplicates and `b` doesn't contain duplicates. So you can use

```
const a = [{name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: false},
  {name: 'Kelly',email: 'kelly@mac.com',flag: true}];
const b = [{name: 'Rana',email: 'rana@mac.com',flag: true},
  {name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: true},
  {name: 'Hank',email: 'Hank@mac.com',flag: false}];

const map = new Map();
for (const o of a) {
  map.set(o.email, o);
}
for (const o of b) {
  if (!map.has(o.email) || !map.get(o.email).flag)
    map.set(o.email, o);
  // else keep the one from a
}
return Array.from(map.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info.

```js
// A.
const A = [{name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: false}, {name: 'Kelly',email: 'kelly@mac.com',flag: true}]
  
// B.
const B = [{name: 'Rana',email: 'rana@mac.com',flag: true}, {name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: true}, {name: 'Hank',email: 'Hank@mac.com',flag: false}]

// Unique Users.
const uniqueUsers = (...arrays) => [...new Map([].concat.apply([], arrays).map(user => [user.email.toLowerCase(), user])).values()]

// Proof.
const C = uniqueUsers(A, B)
console.log(C)

// Optional Filtration By Flag.
const D = C.filter(user => user.flag)
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to use the `.values()` iterator on `userEmailKeyValuePair([...A, ...B])])` and to spread it into a new array. Just pass it directly to `new Map`.

Comment: I also want those with false value which don't have any duplicates. Check the expected output please.

Comment: Hi @Bergi  `values()` is being run on the `Map` to expose its `values` in a destructurable format. I'm open to suggestions if you can think of a better way to do so 

Comment: @wp7 You asked for the `output` to only include `users` who's `flags` evaluated to `true`. Nonetheless, see above ^

Comment: @ArmanCharan Oh, right, I misread where `.values()` is used, I thought you were calling it on the array. Not putting everything in one line might help :-) But still, you can (should) just use `x` instead of `[...x]` if x is an array, or `Array.from(x)` if x is an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `reduce`:

```js
const a = [{name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: false}, {name: 'Kelly',email: 'kelly@mac.com',flag: true}];
const b = [{name: 'Rana',email: 'rana@mac.com',flag: true}, {name: 'Anna',email: 'anna@mac.com',flag: true}, {name: 'Hank',email: 'Hank@mac.com',flag: false}];

let resp = [].concat(a, b)
.reduce((acc, { name, email, flag }) => {
  if(!flag || acc.some(x => x.name == name && x.email == email)) return acc;
  return acc.concat({name, email, flag});
}, [])

console.log(resp);
```